# After an update and few freezes, ubuntu can't restart properly

Tags: 18.04, updates, reboot

I'm facing a peculiar problem with my ubuntu 18.04, Dell computer.

I'm not a huge fan of rebooting on every updates (happened a lot recently) but since Monday few applications refused to worked (they open but nothing is actionable) like the calculator or clicking on "update" from the UI when a new update is available.

Thus today I decided to reboot my computer and then the fun happened.
I got stuck on the DELL black screen with this message (the longest I waited was 20min):

> Found update fwupdate-b950d63c-f9a5-4823-b48d-395e960ab468-0
>
> File \EFI\ubuntu\fw\fwupdate-KXJikb.cap searched

I forced reboot (power off / on) it boots properly but from now on each time I want to reboot, black screen with the message and I have to manually off / on.

Anyone experienced this and would have a hint about what to look for / how to solve it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

My ubuntu18.04 came into the same problem. After contacting to Dell tech support, I ensured that this had nothing to do with the hardware. It is about BIOS upgrading, which should has been 'updated natively in the OS' (like clicking 'update' from UI).

As I still has no idea why it cannot be natively updated, I solved it by Flash BIOS upgrade. I followed the step2 and step3 at [Updating the Dell BIOS in Linux and Ubuntu Environments](https://www.dell.com/support/article/cn/zh/cnbsd1/sln171755/updating-the-dell-bios-in-linux-and-ubuntu-environments?lang=en#updatebios2015). The flash USB has no need to be formatted or cleared. I hope this will help you.